# Planning-Scene: Is it sufficient to publish to "collision_object"?

Tags: ros, moveit, collision-object, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am trying to add and move some objects to my planning_scene in MoveIt. Since I am currently running into weird errors, I wanted to know if it is correct, when I create my collision_object and publish it to */collision_object* OR do I also have to publish it to */planning_scene* as a diff?

Thanks in advance,
Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189728/planning-scene:-is-it-sufficient-to-publish-to-%22collision_object%22?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like both solutions are working with the exact same outcome

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0